# Multiple clip-paths

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I'm trying to make a website layout ideally consisting of multiple divs, where I'd like each one to have a slanted bottom, going into the one below.

Here's a look at the mockup so far:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 10px;
}

.red {
 position: relative;
   height: 500px;
   background: red;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
   clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 5vw));
}
 
.blue {
 height: 500px;
 margin-top: -5vw;
 background: blue;
}

.green {
 height: 500px;
 margin-top: -5vw;
 background: green;
}

.orange {
 height: 500px;
 margin-top: -5vw;
 background: orange;
}

.purple {
 height: 500px;
 margin-top: -5vw;
 background: purple;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
 
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
 
<body>
 <div class="red"></div>
 <div class="blue"></div>
 <div class="green"></div>
 <div class="orange"></div>
 <div class="purple"></div>
</body>
 
</html>
```

As you can tell, I can only get the first div to maintain the apperance I'd like of the slanted bottom.

I've snatched some code from somewhere, and I can get the first div box to slant the way I'd like over the other, using clip-path. My problem is, I'd like for the next div to also have a slanted bottom - presumably by using clip path? - but when I attempt this, it works, but the first 'clip-path slant' reverts back to being non-existant.

Because - as I mentioned earlier - I've snatched the code from somewhere, I do not fully understand the values of the clip-path properties that I'm looking at.

Hopefully I've not been too confusing, and thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is about [stacking-context](https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#the-clip-path) and [painting order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html). if you add `clip-path` to your next element this one will be on the top of the first because it will create a new stacking context and will be painted **later** and since we have the negative margin it will hide the clipped part of the first one.

> A computed value of other than none results in the creation of a
> stacking context the same way that CSS opacity
> does for values other than

A trivial solution is to add `z-index` to correct all this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body>div {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 5vw));
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

.red {
  z-index: 5;
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  z-index: 4;
  margin-top: -5vw;
  background: blue;
}

.green {
  z-index: 3;
  margin-top: -5vw;
  background: green;
}

.orange {
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: -5vw;
  background: orange;
}

.purple {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -5vw;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="orange"></div>
<div class="purple"></div>
```

Another solution to avoid adding many `z-index` is to think differently and instead of creating the slatend part in **the bottom**, we create it in **the top**. Like that we get the advantage of the logicial paiting order and we avoid complication with `z-index`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body>div {
  margin-bottom:-5vw;
  height: 500px;
}

body>div:not(:first-child) {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100%  5vw, 100% 100%, 0 100%);  
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.purple {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="orange"></div>
<div class="purple"></div>
```

Comment: Wonderfull! Makes sense all of the sudden. But your solution creates another answer on my part; what if the purple div was to be my end div? How'd I remove the bottom slant of that one alone?

Comment: @treadwell simply remove the clip path from it ;) ... I simply applied the clip-path to all of them using one selector to avoid repetition and to have a short code ;)

Comment: You absolute genius! I'll go give my glasses a cleanse... Thank you!!